# PHP Function Exists Hash Equals Redeclared

Tags: php

I know that hash_equals is a PHP 5.6>= function and the server that I'm developing for has no intentions of updating from 5.5 to 5.6, so as advised I'm using a similar function for the same effect which is

```
public function hashCheck($know, $user)
{
    if(!function_exists('hash_equals')) {
      function hash_equals($str1, $str2) {
        if(strlen($str1) != strlen($str2)) {
          return false;
        } else {
          $res = $str1 ^ $str2;
          $ret = 0;
          for($i = strlen($res) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) $ret |= ord($res[$i]);
          return !$ret;
        }
      }
    }
    return hash_equals($know, $user);
}
```

The problem I'm getting is an error saying that it is already declared. Now I'm pretty certain that even if it was declared somewhere else that is what the function_exists is for. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message which you get?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare MatchFixers\Helpers\hash_equals() (previously declared in /home/rken90/public_html/dev/app/MatchFixers/Helpers/Hash.php:28) in /home/rken90/public_html/dev/app/MatchFixers/Helpers/Hash.php on line 28"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the namespace. `function_exists` checks from the root namespace whereas you define it within namespace `MatchFixers\Helpers`. This means it checks `\hash_equals` but creates the function as `\MatchFixers\Helpers\hash_equals`. To resolve this you need to add the namespace to the check:

```
if(!function_exists(__NAMESPACE__ . '\hash_equals'))
```

Interestingly this isn't mentioned in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php).

**Edit**

Although I'd actually suggest checking for and creating the function in the root namespace. This then allows for it to be used in other namespaces without having to create a new function in each one.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think it would matter too much about the namespace as it only ever gets called via that one class! Appreciated